# How do I get an Angular input component to submit its data?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular component as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Form field with error messages */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-name',
  templateUrl: 'first-name-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['first-name-input.component.css']
})
export class FirstNameInputComponent {
  firstname = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.firstname.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
  }
}
```

with a template as follows:

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your first name" [formControl]="firstname" required >
    <mat-error *ngIf="firstname.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I embed the component as follows:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <app-first-name></app-first-name>
    </div>
```

The form code is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NumberValidators } from '../app.validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html'
})
export class ContactComponent {
  formModel: FormGroup;
  firstname: string;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formModel = fb.group({
      form_name: ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.formModel.valid) {
      console.log('valid:', this.formModel.value);
    } else {
      console.log('invalid: ', this.formModel.value);
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I fill out the field and press the button, the output to the console is:

`valid: {form_name: ""}`

I.e, empty.

Any idea how to get my component to properly submit its data?

ADDED:

```
<form [formGroup]="formModel" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="messages"></div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <app-first-name></app-first-name>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the form which calls `onSubmit()`

Comment: @AshishRanjan Yes, added.  Thought I did.

Comment: If I get it right, then you want the `form_name` formControl to have the value entered in the firstName field of `app-first-name` cmponent?

Comment: @AshishRanjan -- YEs, that is correct.  Clearly I'm missing something.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: pass ``formModel.value`` to your ``onSubmit()`` . you'll get the value inside the ``onSubmit()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FormGroupDirective**

> This directive accepts an existing FormGroup instance. It will then
>   use this FormGroup instance to match any child FormControl, FormGroup,
>   and FormArray instances to child FormControlName, FormGroupName, and
>   FormArrayName directives.

Ref:https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective#description

You need to use FormGroupDirective to connect the child form with parent group.

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, Validators, ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';

    /** @title Form field with error messages */
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-first-name',
      templateUrl: 'first-name-input.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['first-name-input.component.css'],
      viewProviders:[{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective}]
    })
    export class FirstNameInputComponent implements OnInit {
      firstname;

    constructor(private parent:FormGroupDirective){

    }
    ngOnInit(){
      this.parent.form.addControl('firstname',new 
       FormControl('',Validators.required));
    }

      getErrorMessage() {     
        return this.firstname.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the better answer, I think.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `app-first-name` component needs the formControl from the parent, Have an input property here which will be the formControl.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-name',
  templateUrl: 'first-name-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['first-name-input.component.css']
})
export class FirstNameInputComponent {
  @Input() firstNameControl: FormControl

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.firstNameControl.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
  }
}
```

Pass on the from control from the parent like:

```
<app-first-name [firstNameControl]="formModel?.get('form_name')"></app-first-name>
```